# Struts 2 + Waffle: User principal is always null

Tags: security, jsp, struts2, waffle

I am working on a Web application based on Java, JSP, Struts 2 and Waffle for security. I run it in Tomcat 6. My problem is that I cannot get a principal object in my ActionSupport class. To be more specific,

```
principalProxy.getUserPrincipal()
```

always returns null. When I put this in a .jsp file, however:

```
request.getUserPrincipal()
```

this does not return null. So the information must be available in the original HttpServletRequest object. Of course, I have tried calling getUserPrincipal() on the HttpServletRequest object in the ActionSupport class, but this also returns null.

My ActionSupport class is defined as

```
public class SomeAction extends ActionSupport 
  implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware, PrincipalAware {
  ...
```

Furthermore, my struts.xml defines an action with the servlet-config interceptor set, so the setPrincipalProxy() method does actually get called (verified by print statements). This is my struts.xml (shortened):

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="some" class="com.my.package.SomeAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="servlet-config" />
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
      <param name="excludeParams ">(.*)</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <result name="success">/someresult.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

The web.xml defines a security filter and a filter mapping that should match any URL. Here are the relevant parts:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
  <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>   
  <init-param>
    <param-name>principalFormat</param-name>
    <param-value>fqn</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>roleFormat</param-name>
    <param-value>both</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allowGuestLogin</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>securityFilterProviders</param-name>
    <param-value>
      waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider
      waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider
    </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
    <param-value>
      Negotiate
      NTLM
    </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>    
    <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider/realm</param-name>
    <param-value>WaffleFilterDemo</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>         
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>      
</filter-mapping>
```

When requesting SomeAction, I am prompted with a HTTP Basic Authentication dialog as desired. This shows that the SecurityFilter does in fact get applied, doesn't it? The setPrincipalProxy() method gets called as well. I can get a Principal object in the JSP page. So why is the Principal object always null when I try to access it in SomeAction?

One more thing, I am employing URL rewriting, in case that could have anything to do with it.

EDIT:
In response to batbaatar's request, the setting of the request in Java. Could not be much simpler.

```
@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
  httpRequest = request;
}
```

The instance variable httpRequest is of type HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Can you show us the JAVA part some around where you're getting HttpServletRequest? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I still could not get a user principal object from the HTTPServletRequest. However, I am able to get a principal object from the Session:

```
private String getLoggedInUser() {
  if (httpSession.containsKey(WAFFLE_PRINCIPAL_KEY)) {
    WindowsPrincipal principal = 
      (WindowsPrincipal) httpSession.get(WAFFLE_PRINCIPAL_KEY);
    return principal == null ? "" : principal.getName();
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

The session key is defined as:

```
private static final String WAFFLE_PRINCIPAL_KEY = 
    "waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter.PRINCIPAL";
```

Still curious for an answer to the original question, though.

Comment: have you tried asking the same on struts-user list, might be able to get some insights there

Comment: Can you get user principal by adding these lines? import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
Principal userPrincipal = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getUserPrincipal();